# how to insert 4query at a time in sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hi friend i try to give weather application by fetch by xml parser and all the value display in tableview cell but know i want to insert a data into sqlite database but the problem is that only first case is insert other case are not inserted but i pass 4insert query in my sqlite insert statement how to increment this switch case on by one for store value in database table i writen this code in tableview delegate method tableViewcellforRowAtIndexPath:

```
indexPath++;

switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentcond.Icon]];
            NSLog(@"this is image from server:%@",imageData);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
            [imageData release];
        file://localhost/Users/pradeepyadav/Desktop/JourneyMapper/Journey/Classes/TJourneyTabBar.hcell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];     
            cell.reportdate.text = _forecastInfo.CurrentDateTime;
            //cell.conditionname.text = currentcond.Condition;
            [cell setConditionName:currentcond.Condition];      
            //[cell setConditionName:cond1.Condition];
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",currentcond.Tempf,currentcond.Tempc];
            cell.twodirection.text = currentcond.WindCondition;
            cell.humidity.text = currentcond.Humidity;

            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo]; 
            cell.reportdate.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thursday];
            //cell.conditionname.text = cond1.Condition;
            [cell setConditionName:cond1.Condition];
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond1.Low,cond1.High];
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
            cell.reportdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",friday];
            //cell.conditionname.text = cond2.Condition;
            [cell setConditionName:cond2.Condition];
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond2.Low,cond2.High];
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            cell.weatherimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];
            cell.reportdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sunday];
            //cell.conditionname.text = cond3.Condition;
            [cell setConditionName:cond3.Condition];
            cell.twotemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Temp:%@/%@",cond3.Low,cond3.High];
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Out of Range ",indexPath.row);
            break;
    }
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why its not satisfying the other case? you should always use the case with indexpath.row and the second thing is, it depends how you are calling this method ?